# How to fix iteration without a cause (with an input); in c++?

Tags: c++, validation, iteration

*Just on a starting note, Please excuse the lack of c++ conventions and logic shown in this code. I'm still trying to get around formatting syntax for c++..*

With this small part of a larger application building project, I am trying to create a 'data validation' type subroutine with integers and strings being the main test cases, the input coming from the intended user.

The problem is that each character of the variable input is being iterated over, even if the 'if statements' are outside of the 'for loop' (or in some other cases while loops).

An example of the error being:

```
Enter a value:f1o2o3
Your value is a string
Your value is a integer
Your value is a string
Your value is a integer
Your value is a string
Your value is a integer
```

The extra lines after the first `Your value is a string` and
`Your value is a integer` are unwanted.

I know that I could just instead return the boolean variable `letexists` or `intexsits`, with them both being iterated without a problem. 
However this 'character iterating' problem has been a nuisance in other parts too and I cannot seem to find a definite, understandable fix anywhere.

I am used to using python so this 'iterating over every character while passing parameters' is quite new to me.

I have tried looking into what it could be for multiple days now. Both: searching online and asking others (in person showing them code that has problems) about the 'iteration over each character' problem, however, none seem to know why this happens.

I have solved this problem in the past by breaking a `while(true)` loop after the intended data value has been received, however I understand this is really bad practice and therefore want to figure out how I can improve data validation.

```
#include <iostream> // for std::cin, std::cout
#include <string> // for string datatype
#include <algorithm> // for std::find
#include <iterator> // for std::begin, std::end


using namespace std;

// If the 'cout's are changed to returning functions I will change this to a function itself (using int datacheck(...){...})
void datacheck(string &i) {
    const char nums[] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','\0' };
    const char alph[] = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','\0' };

    for (char& c : i) {
        bool intexists = find(begin(nums), end(nums), c) != end(nums);
        bool letexists = find(begin(alph), end(alph), c) != end(alph);

        if (letexists || (letexists && intexists))
            cout << "Your value is a string" << endl;
        // This will be changed for a return value

        else if (!letexists && intexists)
            cout << "Your value is a integer" << endl;
        // This will be changed for a return value
        else
            cout << "Your value has an erogenous input (Special characters or non-letter/ number related stuff.";

    }
}

int main(void) {
    string checkedvalue;
    cout << "Enter a value: ";
    cin >> checkedvalue;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(512, '\n');
    datacheck(checkedvalue);

    return 0;
}
```

I have realised that it may be because each character is being sent through individually into the subroutine, however, if this is the case I am still unsure how to fix this.

Just to end off...
Overall, an explained solution for why the iterating happens and how it can be fixed will be greatly appreciated. If possible for general cases, however, just this case will be extremely helpful nonetheless.

Thank you.

Comment: 'even when the if statements are outside the loop' that's not true in the code above, the if statements are inside the loop. I guess you've been decieved by pythons weird indentation rules, which don't apply to C++

Comment: @john Oh s**t I just realised, they are in the for loop. That's my bad. Although in my code I fixed that and it still iterated nonetheless when trying to data validate.

Comment: Think a little about your condition `letexists || (letexists && intexists)`... If `letexists` is `true` then the whole condition is true (and `letexists && intexists` will not even be evaluated). If `letexists ` is `false` then `letexists && intexists` will *also* be `false`.

Comment: acutally I was about to vtc because it can be considered as typo, though I felt like writing an answer;)

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, i dont understand all of what you write. What I did understnad is

> The problem is that each character of the variable input is being
>   iterated over, even if the 'if statements' are outside of the 'for
>   loop'

And that is wrong!

```
for (char& c : i) {
        bool intexists = find(begin(nums), end(nums), c) != end(nums);
        bool letexists = find(begin(alph), end(alph), c) != end(alph);

        if (letexists || (letexists && intexists))
            cout << "Your value is a string" << endl;
        // This will be changed for a return value

        else if (!letexists && intexists)
            cout << "Your value is a integer" << endl;
        // This will be changed for a return value
        else
            cout << "Your value has an erogenous input (Special characters or non-letter/ number related stuff.";

    }
```

All this above is "the for loop". In simple terms the syntax for a (ranged based) for loop is

```
for (char& c : i) {
     // body of the loop
}
```

Your code will be more clear and readable if you use `{}` also for the if, even if not needed and proper intendation:

```
for (char& c : i) {
    bool intexists = find(begin(nums), end(nums), c) != end(nums);
    bool letexists = find(begin(alph), end(alph), c) != end(alph);

    if (letexists || (letexists && intexists)) {
        cout << "Your value is a string" << endl;
    } else if (!letexists && intexists) {
        cout << "Your value is a integer" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Your value has an erogenous input (Special characters or non-letter/ number related stuff.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll take heed of this, sorry for the confusion caused.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the standard provides different ways to checks if an string contains alpha/numeric values:

- Check if all characters are numeric: [`std::isalnum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum)
- Check if all characters are alpha: [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha)

So you can replace part of your code with:

```
const all_numeric = std::all_of(std::begin(str), std::end(str), [](const auto c) {
    return std::isalnum(c);
})

const all_alpha = std::all_of(std::begin(str), std::end(str), [](const auto c) {
    return std::isalpha(c);
})
```

So to solve your problem, you can start by creating a helper function that checks if a string is a number by using standard functions like `strtool` or recycle what we did later:

```
bool is_number(const std::string& s) {
    return !s.empty() && std::find_if(s.begin(), 
        s.end(), [](char c) { return !std::isdigit(c); }) == s.end();
}
```

Now that you know if the string is a number or not, you can check if your string contains any weird character, and discard it.

#### Updates:

```
void datacheck(string &i) {
    const auto intexists = is_number(i);
    if (intexists) {
       // do whatever
       return;
    }

    const all_alpha = std::all_of(std::begin(str), std::end(str), [](const auto c) {
         return std::isalpha(c); 
    });
    if (all_alpha) {
        // do whatever
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This helps quite a bit, I'll try implementing this into my code to see if it fits; thank you for responding

Comment: Check the last update with a clean implementation, I hope it helps. I did not understand your problem properly @RyanSutton